# How to print an instance of some class in jenkins shared library without explicitly calling toString() method

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have jenkins shared library. It has some CustomClass.groovy with overridden toString() method:

```
package com.jenkins

class CustomClass {

    CustomClass(){
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        return "custom_class"
    }
}
```

And I have the Jenkinsfile:

```
@Library("sharedlib@to-string")
import com.jenkins.CustomClass

println("1")
println(new CustomClass())

println("2")
println("prefix: " + new CustomClass())

println("3")
println("prefix: " + new CustomClass().toString())
```

It produces following output:

```
[Pipeline] echo
1
[Pipeline] echo
2
[Pipeline] echo
custom_class
[Pipeline] echo
3
[Pipeline] echo
prefix: custom_class
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I have some confusion about that output:

1. Why didn't the first example print anything?
2. Why didn't the first example print prefix? Why only instance?
3. Why are second and third examples different? Why here I see prefix, but don't see it in the second example. Why the first example it printed nothing, but third is okay as expected. After all, println() method uses toString() in second example implicitly.

Comment: in plain groovy all works as you expect. question to jenkins pipeline...

Comment: Yes. In plain groovy everything is ok. But running in jenkins environment shows strange results.

Comment: what about `echo "${new CustomClass()}"`

Comment: same result - nothing.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [Pipeline Readme :-)](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/README.md#technical-design)

> Note in particular that `@Override`s of methods defined in binary classes, such as `Object.toString()`, should in general be marked `@NonCPS` since it will commonly be binary code calling them.

the following will work correctly:

```
class A{
    @NonCPS
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "A[123]"
    }
}

node {
    def a = new A()
    echo('1 >>>')
    echo(message: "Hello ${a}")
    echo('2 >>>')
    echo(message: "Hello " + a)
    echo('3 >>>')
    echo(message: "Hello " + a.toString())
}
```